# order of primary and auto_increment column is not working properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

After reseting identity column i have came up with this issue.
I am using postgres with pgadmin 4 , the problem is that the order of the primary key and auto_increment column is not working properly its showing correct values but in random series for example.

### Student Table

```
 | id | name |

 | 3  | bob  |
 | 1  | sam|
 | 2  | tim  |
```

When open the pgadmin 4 table I want the table structure to show like this.

All the constraints are working properly but the order is not working . I want to fix the column values in order for example.

### Student Table

```
 | id | name |
 | 1  | sam |
 | 2  | tim |
 | 3  | bob |
```

Comment: how you are fetching the data from student table?

Comment: Which *order*? SQL tables represent *unordered* sets of rows, there is no notion of inherent ordering, which makes your question rather unclear.

Comment: I have edit the question please read @GMB

Comment: create a view that selects from the table and has the wanted ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to fix the column values in order for example

Then use an `order by`

```
select id, name
from student
order by id;
```

Using an `order by` is the **only** way to guarantee a sorted result.

Comment: Please read the question again

Comment: I did, and using an `order by` is the **only** way to guarantee a sorted result.

Comment: I want to show in the table structure in pgadmin4 because , if I follow your answer I need to replace my query in 1000 places

Comment: Using an `order by` is the **only** way to guarantee a sorted result

Comment: please understand the problem can we continue this in chat

Comment: I do understand the problem. But rows in a table are not sorted nor do they have any implied default ordering. The **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use an `order by`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222766/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-a-horse-with-no-name).